# Are Java compilers translated for different locales?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, localization

As a general rule, are Java compilers localised? Are the compilers capable of emitting errors/warnings in languages besides English?

Information on any of the available Java compilers is welcome. In fact, historical or technical reasons why localisation is not considered for any language compilers is welcome.

NOTE: I am not asking this question to solve any problem I have, it is just sheer curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't know anything about javac localization, I will answer to a part of the question:

GCC (the C and C++ compilers at least) are localized in Ubuntu, so localization certainly is done. However, the drawbacks of localization include that it is more difficult to google for the error messages online, or to describe a problem on StackOverflow. Programmers also absolutely must know English, so there is little benefit on localization.

Comment: I'm surprised they wouldn't have tried to solve the Googling problem by including short, unique error codes. I wonder how much of a barrier the expectation of English competency is to young children interested in programming. +1

Comment: Microsoft actually uses such codes, but others haven't caught up on it for some reason. I don't think the error messages being in English even slows down learning to program. I started coding before I could read, just copying the BASIC commands my mom had written on paper.

Comment: you're probably right about English not being a barrier - when learning a programming language, most of the compiler errors may as well be in a foreign language :-)